# How to compile a c++ program using Dev C++ compiler in windows command prompt?

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, dev-c++

I installed Dev C++ in windows and I worked with that IDE, however I want to compile my program, `prog1.cpp`, in windows command prompt.
I opened cmd in current directory and I have tried following commands that not worked:

1. cl prog1.cpp
2. cc prog1.cpp
3. gcc prog1 prog1.cpp
4. g++ -o prog1 prog1.cpp
5. c prog1.cpp
6. cl /EHsc prog1.cpp

All of above commands cause this error: `command not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.`:

***Note: I don't want to install visual studio and using `cl /EHsc prog1.cpp`

What is the command to compile a program in cmd using Dev C++ compiler?

Comment: Dev-C++ isn't a compiler; it's a (very outdated) IDE

Comment: Note that integrated development environment (IDE) bundles the compiler with build and analysis tools.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dev-C++ is not a compiler. It's an IDE.

You need to add the path to the compilers before you can use them.

Assume you installed Dev-C++ to `C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp`, then you need to add the following paths to `%PATH%` variable:

```
C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin
C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\libexec\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0
C:\Program Files\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\mingw32\bin
```

You can add it temporarily to one Command Prompt session with

```
path %PATH%;<more paths here>
```

Or refer to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=edit+path+windows) to learn how to add it permanently to your system.

After resolving the `%PATH%` issue, you'll be able to compile your programs with `gcc` (C) or `g++` (C++). Note that `c` and `cl` are still unavailable (because they're not installed).

Comment: Thanks @iBug , with a bit correction as follows it works for me: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\bin` and 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\libexec\gcc\x86_64-w64-mingw32\4.9.2` and 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin`